# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=.Southwest }

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am pretty new to Android and I am having an issue. I keep getting the No Activity found to handle Intent error. I am trying to start a new activity with the button click.

I have looked at all the other answers and they were either very specific to the question as in, the answers did not apply to my question, or it was saying to make sure the activity names match, which mine do.

Manifest

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.madonk.louisiana.festivals"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>        
         </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Southwest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_southwest" >

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

> ```
> package com.madonk.louisiana.festivals;
>
> import android.os.Bundle; 
> import android.app.Activity; 
> import android.content.Intent; 
> import android.view.Menu; 
> import android.view.View; 
> import android.widget.Button;
>
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>   Button southwest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_southwest);
>   southwest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>       public void onClick(View v) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>           startActivity(new Intent());            }       });
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
>     return true;
> } }
> ```

LogCat

```
    07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=.Southwest }
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at com.madonk.louisiana.festivals.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:22)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-22 21:08:35.179: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: First, you can't have two Activities with action MAIN and category LAUNCHER, this is just nonsense if you think about it. Second, you should post the code the logcat and the code that gives you the exception.

Comment: I deleted the MAIN and LAUNCHER and still get the error.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to not mislead people.

Comment: You have set up 2 Launchers! Delete the Intent Filters from your second Activity, you probably don't need them. But if you do, change the second one to .DEFAULT and the Action to .SOUTHWEST

Comment: Please post the code where you create the Intent.

Comment: sorry, i am still pretty new to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not show the source code for where you are starting the activity. Based on the LogCat output, my guess is that you are trying:

```
startActivity(new Intent(".Southwest"));
```

Instead, use:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Southwest.class));
```

Comment: Oh, man! Beat me be 2 minutes. And it is 11PM on a Sunday here. I think we both probably need to get a life ;-)

Comment: when i tried that it created an error and told me to insert what is there now

Comment: @Madonk: Alas, we cannot readily guess what "it" is, since you did not provide a definition for that pronoun. "what is there now" is an empty `Intent`, which will not do you any good. If "it" is `this`, your problem is that you are using an anonymous inner class for your `OnClickListener`, which means that you need to use `MainActivity.this` to reference the activity instance.

Comment: sorry, it is eclipse. the error pops up and tells me that the constructor Intent is undefined and offers me a quick fix, which changes my code to what is there now

Comment: @Madonk: The `Intent` constructor that takes a `Context` (like `MainActivity.this`) and a Java class (like `Southwest.class`) definitely exists. Here is a sample project demonstrating an explicit `Intent`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Activities/Explicit

Comment: I am still getting that same error and suggested fix. I have checked out that link, but I do not know what showOther is and do not know how to impliment showOther.

Comment: @Madonk: `showOther()` is a method, implemented on the `ExplicitIntentsDemoActivity` class: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Activities/Explicit/src/com/commonsware/android/exint/ExplicitIntentsDemoActivity.java

Comment: ok, I got it fixed. I should have "startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Southwest.class));" I have seen this before and should have known better. I have been working on this app for like a year, but between training and computers crashing, it's taking me a while. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've not posted any code, but I'm assuming that when you start the Southwest activity you are probably creating the `Intent` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(".Southwest");
```

This creates an `Intent` with ACTION=".Southwest". You want to start a specific class, so you need to create an explicit `Intent` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Southwest.class);
```

That will create an `Intent` for a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

posting here to help others who have stumbled across this

code should be

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Southwest.class));
```